# Is there a way to trust HTTPS certificate via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, http, https, single-page-application, fetch-api

I am currently developing a single page application to manage devices in my local network over HTTP. My plan was to make this app publicly available over HTTPS, so other can manage their devices with it. However, any traffic over HTTP is blocked. For ease of use, I don't want to manually install a self-signed certificate on every client.

My idea was to create a self-signed CA that can be used by any device to issue a certificate to itself. These certificates are of course blocked by every browser, because the CA is self-signed.

Is there a way, in the best case via Javascript, to trust the CA only for XHRs from my single page application?

Comment: JavaScript does not have that power